# HttpEntityEnclosingRequest setEntity from InputStreamEntity gets parameter names wrong

Tags: java, post, parameters, proxy, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm writing a proxy server as a servlet. I'm using HttpClient as the proxy client. When I get a POST request with a body, I am trying to copy the body into the rewritten proxy request using an InputStreamEntity. The target servlet can't find the parameters. After debugging, it appears that the parameters are getting renamed with an array notation: for example, "name" becomes "name[0]".

Here's the code:

```
    // Create the actual proxy request.
String proxyRequestUri =
  rewriteUrlFromRequest(servletRequest, target, null);
HttpRequest proxyRequest = null;
if (servletRequest.getHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH) != null
    || servletRequest.getHeader(HttpHeaders.TRANSFER_ENCODING) != null) {
  HttpEntityEnclosingRequest eProxyRequest =
    new BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest(servletRequest.getMethod(),
                                        proxyRequestUri);

    // Copy the entity from the request body.
    eProxyRequest.setEntity(new InputStreamEntity(servletRequest.getInputStream(),
                                                  servletRequest.getContentLength()));
  // Set the enclosing request into the request to return.
  proxyRequest = eProxyRequest;
} else {
  // No message body, just create a basic request.
  proxyRequest =
    new BasicHttpRequest(servletRequest.getMethod(), proxyRequestUri);
}
return proxyRequest;
```

I verified the names are correct going in by getting the parameter map from the request and dumping it, everything looked fine. The same dump on the proxied target server showed the names with "[0]" appended, so the string compares in that code failed to find the parameters.

I replaced the above code with this code, which copies the parameters from the map into a new form encoded entity, and it worked fine:

```
    // Create the actual proxy request.
String proxyRequestUri =
  rewriteUrlFromRequest(servletRequest, target, null);
HttpRequest proxyRequest = null;
if (servletRequest.getHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH) != null
    || servletRequest.getHeader(HttpHeaders.TRANSFER_ENCODING) != null) {
  HttpEntityEnclosingRequest eProxyRequest =
    new BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest(servletRequest.getMethod(),
                                        proxyRequestUri);

  if (servletRequest.getContentType().equals("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")) {
    // Extract the parameter map and create a new form entity.
    Map<String, String[]> map = servletRequest.getParameterMap();
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    for (String name : map.keySet()) {
      String[] array = map.get(name);
      for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, array[i]));
      }
    }
    eProxyRequest.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
  } else {
    // Copy the entity from the request body.
    eProxyRequest.setEntity(new InputStreamEntity(servletRequest.getInputStream(),
                                                  servletRequest.getContentLength()));
  }
  // Set the enclosing request into the request to return.
  proxyRequest = eProxyRequest;
} else {
  // No message body, just create a basic request.
  proxyRequest =
    new BasicHttpRequest(servletRequest.getMethod(), proxyRequestUri);
}
return proxyRequest;
```

I don't think this workaround is general enough to handle everything possible, so I'd like to resolve the original problem if I can.

Comment: I encountered the same problem. Seems that it's necessary to build correct entity and don't just rely on InputStreamEntity for all cases.